# Cannot dual boot 14.04 with Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

My problem is that my HP laptop came with four partitions on my 750Gb hard disk. I have tried to "shrink" the largest partition to 320Gb with success in order to create a "Swap area" and a Primary area with the "/" designator. When I reboot with my USB Flash "Live drive", the installation program will start to work. I go through the various steps until I am at the installation choice. I chose "Something else".

On all the instructional videos, I am supposed to have a free space created by the new unallocated partition. Instead, the installation software considers my new unallocated partition as "UNUSABLE" and because of this, I am unable to dual boot 14.04. I have learned that the problem is those preexisting four partitions (three created by Windows 7 and one created by Hewlett Packard). I have learned that I cannot have more than four partitions on this hard disk.

One video found a solution by removing one of the partitions (I assume it was the "HP_Tools" partition). When the fourth partition was removed, the "UNUSABLE" partition NOW becomes "Free Space" and the Primary and Swap area partitions can now be created and Ubuntu 14.04 can be installed as a dual boot.

I do not know if this solution is correct or proper. What puzzles me is that I was running dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 without any problems. The "Upgrade Manager" suggested that I upgrade to 14.04. I tried and that is when my installation nightmare began. The Upgrade manager loaded 14.04 to my laptop, BUT 14.04 would not boot up!! I created the USB drive with 14.04 installation and tried to use it to help boot up. I accidentally wiped out the entire hard disk and had it dedicated to 14.04. It works!! But I wanted a dual boot. I have reloaded Windows 7 and am trying to dual boot 14.04. None of your instructions are helping me because of my 4 partitions.

Is there any other way to dual boot 14.04 WITHOUT removing that 4th partition?

Comment: It seems like there is some information here unrelated to your problem. Could you edit this to focus on your problem, and break it into paragraphs so it is easier to read?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your problem in full meaning. But I think you should try with logical partitions. **Logical partitions** resemble primary partitions, although the number of logical partitions that can be created on a single physical disk is **unlimited**.

Unfortunately I don't know what is the point to have those trash partitions like Hewlett Packard and other *created* by Windows7.
I have Win7 and Ubuntu, for me, at this moment it's look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSZBY.png)

My tip is just: Try to create **logical** partition for *linux*, create **primary** partition for *swap*, create **primary** partition for *win7*. Inside extended partition try to create those 3(?) partitions in NTFS filesystem for Windows7 Hewlett etc (or leave free space for them?), but I'm not sure those partitions will work for win7 with this combination in extended, and I really don't know what is the point of their exist and how their work. :( Then try to install Win7 first, after that, install Ubuntu.

Good luck with this, have fun

p.s If you load Ubuntu live from 14.04 you should have preinstalled **gparted** on board, no need to work in installation program

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered a solution to my dual boot problem. While reading an HP support forum, I learned that HP sets up its computers with 4 Primary Partitions (two for Windows and 2 for HP information). When I used Windows Disk Manager to "shrink" the largest Windows 7 Primary partition into a 323Gb unallocated empty space, I unwittingly created a 5th Primary partition on my Hard disk drive. Ubuntu installation software did NOT know what to do with the 5th Primary partition. This girl from the HP Support forum came up with a brilliant idea. Instead of erasing one of the HP Primary partitions, she converted the HP Primary partitions into Logical Partitions. This action reduced the number of primary partitions. She recommended a download of a free app called "EaseUS Partition Master Free" which converted my HP Recovery Primary partition into an HP Recovery Logical partition. The Ubuntu installataion software NOW saw the unallocated 323Gb of empty space as USABLE (because it became the new 4th Primary partition) and immediately took over and installed the Ubuntu 14.04LTS as a dual boot with Windows 7. I NOW have dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows 7.  Everything works. I am happy. By the way, I discovered that the Ubuntu installation software (the "Install along with Windows" option) created a Swap area of 16Gb which is exactly the amount of RAM memory on my laptop.